# Nested JSON file to Dataframe with Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, dataframe, nested

This is my first post on this very useful website and I hope I am in the right section.

I need to load and manipulate a big json file (~250MB) which is available online. You can see the files "examples" at this address: https://www.eia.gov/opendata/bulkfiles.php

I'm interested in the PET file but they have all a similar structure.

I want to keep only 3 fields:
series_id, date (first field of nested object data), value (second field of data)

I've been able to import all the data using loops and json.loads(line) but I'm quite sure there is a more efficient way to achieve what I need.

I also tried other "techniques" mentioned on various website (melt, stack) but without any success.

So basically I'm "stuck" after below statements

```
testDF = pd.read_json(jsonfile, lines=True, orient='Split')
testDF = testDF[['series_id', 'data']]
```

Which gives me this output

```
series_id  \ data
0  PET.M_EPC00U_FPF_R48_MBBLD.M   \  [[201711, 32], [201710, 27], [201709, 26], [20...
```

While I would like this

```
series_id \ date \ value
PET.M_EPC00U_FPF_R48_MBBLD.M \ 201711 \ 32
PET.M_EPC00U_FPF_R48_MBBLD.M \ 201710 \ 27
PET.M_EPC00U_FPF_R48_MBBLD.M \ 201709 \ 26
```

It seems so simple to explain...

Thanks in advance for your help and your time.

Jérôme

Comment: `testDF = testDF[['series_id', 'data']]` clobbers the original value of `TestDF`. Avoid redefining variables.

Comment: Try something along the lines of `testDF.select(col("series_id"), explode(col("data")))`.

Comment: Hi 9000. Thanks for your prompt feedback ! Unfortunately, I'm not sure that I understand your suggestion. Are you saying that I should "browse" my dataframe line by line ? Something like "for line in testDF: "

Comment: [`explode()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.explode) turns a list in a field in a number of rows, one row per list element (a bit like `flatMap`). This is how you can turn your data into the form you suggested. I hope this helps.